# Laravel app.js: Uncaught ReferenceError jQuery / $ / moment is not defined - how to use this?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

I had a working application with all libraries imported via CDNs.

To be always up to date, I thought I should switch to installing them via npm and use Laravel mix.

I solved the reference error for a while, but now it pops up again if I want to include another library.

My current main app.js file looks like this:

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import "bootstrap";
import "jquery.typewatch";
require("jquery-autosize");
import "cookieconsent";

// require("moment"); <-- if I uncomment this, the error is raised
import * as tt from "./main" // this is my main normal javascript file
// In my main file I successfully used: const moment = require('moment'); 
window.tt = tt;
```

I just wanted to use https://www.chartjs.org/ and that (for timeline chart) requires moment.js. So I tried to just require or import moment in my app.js, but then I receive more errors:

```
main.js?f32a:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at Object.eval (main.js?f32a:47)
    at eval (main.js:856)
    at Object../resources/js/main.js (app.js?id=83126169b9f96873c6fd:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=41f053ba9a94d81b39f8:80)
    at eval (app.js?6d40:1)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js?id=83126169b9f96873c6fd:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=41f053ba9a94d81b39f8:80)
    at Object.0 (app.js?id=83126169b9f96873c6fd:55)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js?id=41f053ba9a94d81b39f8:80)
    at checkDeferredModules (manifest.js?id=41f053ba9a94d81b39f8:46)


uebersicht:2480 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at uebersicht:2480

jquery.dataTables.min.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:18
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:18

dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8
    at dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js:8
....
```

All because I just included another library. So I guess, I messed this up and don't understand what happens really.

BTW I am running `npm run watch` in the background which compiles the files successfully.

## My other files look like this:

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extractVendors();

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.version();
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    //mix.version();
} else {
    mix.sourceMaps();
}
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery'
            }),
            // momentjs: strip all locales except “de”
            new MomentLocalesPlugin({
                localesToKeep: ['de'],
            }),
        ],
    }
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.9",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jquery-autosize": "^1.18.18",
        "jquery.typewatch": "^3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
    }
}
```

**resources/views/layout/footer.blade.php**

```
<!-- ... --->
<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){ // <-- this line now triggers the error
        // js stuff
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is moment.js??

Comment: @A.ANoman you mean in the footer? Should not be required, or? As it was installed via npm (see package.json). The error happens when I try to add it to app.js

Comment: I was able to get it working (but I still have no clue why - or what I did wrong):
In app.js I used `window.moment = require("moment");` instead and added `moment: 'moment'` in webpack.mix.js in the `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({` object.